# How do I control domain computer idle lock timeout via GPO?

Tags: active-directory

Everything I find online makes reference to screen savers, but we don't use screen savers... our displays go to sleep, therefore, I don't want to "force" a screen saver, etc...

I'd simply like to specify how long a domain joined computer should be idle before it locks the user...

Update:
My computer locks after X minutes of inactivity... no screen saver starts, I simply see the windows lock screen.  This seems to involve neither a screen saver, nor a display sleep.

Comment: I honestly don't see the difference between what you're trying to achieve and forcing an idle screen to turn off after an X number of minutes, add the option to require a password on wake up too.

Comment: My domain joined computers lock after an idle period.  The display continues to stay on, windows lock screen is shown, and no screensaver is shown.  I'm asking how to change the "idle timeout" before windows locks?

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly done with the screen saver + require password on wake up. I beleive this is found under User Configuration \ Policies \ Administrative Templates \ Control Panel \ Personalisation in Server 2k8.

Thats how I have done it in large environments anyway. Make sure you specify a screen saver explicitly in your GPO since this doesn't work if no screensaver is specified.